# Why some work and some not ( Pointer and Non )

Tags: c, pointers

```
#include <stdio.h>

void swap1(int a, int b)
{
    int tmp;

    tmp = a;
    a = b;
    b = tmp;
    return;
}

int main()
{
    int x = 1, y = 2;

    swap1(x,y);
    printf("%d %d",x,y);
    return 0;
}
```

I don't understand why without Pointer these will not work but with Pointer it will work normally. I have search about it on Google and saw a few question about it but I still don't understand it after reading all the answers.

but this code work normally without using Pointer

```
#include <stdio.h>

int padovan(int n);

int main()
{
    int n;
    printf("Enter number : ");
    scanf("%d",&n);
    printf("Result : %d",padovan(n));
}

int padovan(int x)   
{
    if(x == 0 || x == 1 || x == 2)
        return 1;
    else if(x > 2)
        return padovan(x-2) + padovan(x-3);
}
```

Comment: Arguments are passed by *value*. That means when you call `swap1` the values of `x` and `y` are *copied* into the local argument variables `a` and `b`. Any modifications to `a` and `b` only happens to those local variables, the original `x` and `y` variables in the `main` function remains unmodified.

Comment: As for why `padovan` works, it's because it uses the passed value in the variable `x` to calculate a value which is then returned. It doesn't try to modify the argument itself.

Comment: This is what I'm understanding correct me if I'm wrong. What I understand is that it passed the value of x and y which are 1 and 2 into a and b by copying the value and not making x = a , y = b so whatever happened in swap1 isn't happening in int main
but in second code it  work because it didnt print the x but print the padovan itself ?

Comment: "I have search about it on Google and saw a few question" Don't do that. Read the chapter about functions in your C programming book. You can't learn C through various fragmented internet sources, you need to learn the fundamental parts of the language through conventional studies first. That means reading a book and/or taking classes.

Comment: @WWoPPoWW no, it works because `padowan` actually returns a value, unlike the original `swap` (which doesn't return anything)

Comment: @Lundin Oh don't worry I read it from professor's slide and even listen to him again in video but still not understand because the slide is only the code and not explanation and professor kinda rush it so I came here to find similar question

Comment: @Shark Can you explain why Swap can't return anything ? From what I guess is that because it can't have 2 return values?

Comment: @WWoPPoWW yes, thats partially it - not being able to return two things. But usually when you want to return more than 1 thing, you pass those (pointers) ito the method itself as arguments, and the method fills them up with results. Tl;dr - in order for `swap` to return two things, you need to pass pointers; the swap actually swaps them and does nothing else; in `main` the values held by those two pointers are swapped.  Or, if you really want to return multiple things, just return one thing (e.g. a `struct`) containing all the things you wanted to return.

Comment: @WWoPPoWW So this professor is teaching you how functions work and while doing that they brought up recursive functions? If so they should be fired from their job. Or is this padovan function just something you typed out yourself?

Comment: The second part is the "pass-by-value` and "pass-by-reference". Integers are always passed by value. so integers that come into the method can't "exit" the method with any different value.

Comment: @Lundin I didn't type this padovan by myself I copied it from the slide. Professor teach these to me in order Loop --> Function and Parameter --> Loop recursion --> array --> pointer

Comment: @WWoPPoWW Well they need to get fired then. Pass parameters by value or pointer is very fundamental stuff - recursive functions is an exotic dangerous detail of the language with little to no value at all. It shouldn't be taught at (all) beginner classes and certainly not before the students are comfortable with how to use ordinary functions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```c
void swap1(int a, int b)
{
    int tmp
    tmp = a; 
    a = b;
    b = tmp;
    return; 
}
```

You're passing `a` and `b` by value, which means, when you pass `a` and `b`, the compiler makes a *copy* of `a` and `b`, not changing the actual value of `a` and `b`

If you want to make this to work, you have to use some pointers:

```c
void swap(int *a, int *b) {

   int tmp;
   tmp = *a;    // save the value at address x 
   *a = *b;     // put y into x 
   *b = tmp ;   // put tmp into y 
  
   return;
}
```

```c
int padovan(int x)   
{
    if(x == 0 || x == 1 || x == 2)
        return 1;
    else if(x > 2)
        return padovan(x-2) + padovan(x-3);
}
```

This code is fine. `padovan()` returns an `int` and you're printing that. You're not modifying any arguments in `padovan()`.